# When I call DriveApp.createFile(image) the image saved is corrupted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I get the error "No Preview Available" when I try to open it. I am trying to get an image from an external website.

Here are my code attempts:

```
var contentType = "image/jpeg";
var options = {
    "method" : "get",
    "contentType": contentType,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
};

var url = "www.externalwebsite.com/12344.jpg";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
var blob = response.getBlob();
blob.setContentTypeFromExtension();

Logger.log(blob.getContentType());
var image = blob.getAs(contentType);

var file = DriveApp.createFile("file1.jpg",blob,contentType);

var file2 = DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(blob, MimeType.JPEG).getAs(MimeType.JPEG).setName('file2.jpg'));

var file3 = DriveApp.createFile(blob);

var data = Utilities.base64Decode(blob, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
var blobFile = Utilities.newBlob(data, MimeType.JPEG, "file4.jpg");
     DriveApp.createFile(blobFile);
```

Also tried using Advanced Drive :

```
var file5 = {
    title: 'file5.jpg',
    mimeType: 'image/jpeg'
};
file = Drive.Files.insert(file5, blob);
```

Comment: In my environment, ``file3`` is created as an image using a sample URL. But I think that this doesn't replicate your issue. So in order to replicate your situation, can you provide a sample URL? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike you are right this does work on other images... must be a privacy setting.

Comment: In my environment, ``file3`` can be created as an image using a sample URL. Can I ask you about the meaning of "must be a privacy setting"? I couldn't understand about it from your question. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.